# How to get user profile info from Azure Rest Api with user_impersonation as scope

Tags: azure, api, rest

I've an Azure AD app setup, the Rest api's under scope: user_impersonation works but I also need user profile info from some GET API request (with same scope as I cannot have two scopes under one access token). I could not find a suitable API for it.So, any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are making requests to different APIs, you will need to request separate access tokens for this information.

In the case of user profile information, you will need to request a token for the Graph API resource with the `User.Read` scope.

Depending on the type of application, you can either request this information [on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) or [as a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service). When requesting as a service, you need to grant the `User.Read.All` permission instead ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#microsoft-graph-permission-names).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Profile API in Microsoft Graph to retrieve yourself and another user profile.

Using Profile API use for retrieve the sing-in user profile information together Azure AD or account information. This information we can use in application as requirements and we can store as requirements.

when you use these API you will need to valid permissions to access profile information.
Example : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/profile/

[image]

More information about Use the Profile API read these [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/profile-example?view=graph-rest-beta) by Microsoft Documents.